# SSL Certification Verify Failed on Heroku Redis

Tags: ssl, flask, heroku, redis

I'm deploying a flask app on Heroku using a Redis premium plan. I get the following error: 'SSL Certification Verify Failed'. Attempted fixes:

- Downgrading to Redis 5
- Passing `ssl_cert_reqs=None` to the `Redis` constructor in `redis-py`

A solution to this problem could be:

1. Explain how to disable TLS certification on heroku redis premium plans
2. Explain how to make TLS certification work on heroku redis premium plans

From Heroku's docs, this may be a hint: 'you must enable TLS in your Redis client’s configuration in order to connect to a Redis 6 database'. I don't understand what this means.

Answer (score 9):

I solved my problem by adding `?ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE` to the end of `REDIS_URL` in my Heroku config.

Comment: this is the way

Comment: This worked for me when I set it specifically to `?ssl_cert_reqs=none` (CERT_NONE raised an "invalid flag" error)

Comment: This won't stay if you are using Heroku Data for Redis or another addon since the environment variable is managed by Heroku.

Comment: @drweird Is correct. The workaround I applied for this was to leave the Heroku environment variables untouched and append `?ssl_cert_reqs=none` to the Redis URL in the Flask `config.py` file instead.

Answer (score 6):

The docs are actually incorrect, you have to set SSL to verify_none because TLS happens automatically.

From Heroku support:

> "Our data infrastructure uses self-signed certificates so certificates
> can be cycled regularly... you need to set the verify_mode
> configuration variable to OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE"

I solved this by setting the ssl_params to verify_none:

```
ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE } }
```

For me it was where I config redis (in a sidekiq initializer):

```
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], size: 1, network_timeout: 5, 
    ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE } }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], size: 7, network_timeout: 5, 
    ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE } }
end
```

Comment: Can you please explain what a sidekiq initializer is and how it relates to a flask app?

Comment: Sidekiq is a background processing gem, since it connects with redis I set the SSL config there to fix the same error you got. You can probably do the same (verify_none SSL) wherever you're configuring redis.

Comment: @Joe'sIdeas can you provide a link for the Heroku support quote, please? I couldn't find it anywhere :/ (I have a related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834575/how-to-enable-tls-for-redis-6-on-sidekiq)

Comment: @ogirginc there isn't a link, that was from a conversation with support, looks like the verify none worked for you though, nice 

Comment: @Joe'sIdeas yep! Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

You can disable TLS certification on Heroku by downgrading to Redis 5 and passing `ssl_cert_reqs=None` to the `Redis` constructor.

```
$ heroku addons:create heroku-redis:premium-0 --version 5
```

```py
from redis import ConnectionPool, Redis
import os
connection_pool = ConnectionPool.from_url(os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'))
app.redis = Redis(connection_pool=connection_pool, ssl_cert_reqs=None)
```

My mistake was not doing both at the same time.

An ideal solution would explain how to configure TLS certification for Redis 6.

Answer (score 2):

If using the `django-rq` wrapper and trying to deal with this, be sure to not use the `URL` parameter with `SSL_CERTS_REQS`.  There is an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/rq/django-rq/issues/508) that describes this all, but basically you need to specify each connection param instead of using the URL.

Comment: Thanks, I was facing the same issue in `django-rq` and your solution helped!

Answer (score 2):

On Heroku (assuming Heroku Redis addon), the redis TLS route already has the `ssl_cert_reqs` param sorted out. A common oversight that can cause errors in cases like this on heroku is: using `REDIS_URL` over `REDIS_TLS_URL`.

**Solution:**

`redis_url = os.environ.get('REDIS_TLS_URL')`

Comment: This works for "Mini Heroku Data for Redis" only, not the "Premium" one.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into difficulty on this but finally got it resolved...

A lot of documentation and posts on this topic are unclear. I've requested Heroku update their documentation on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-redis#connecting-in-python to include a specific change to the `Procfile`.

It's sort of mentioned above but refers to "Heroku config" instead of the `Procfile` specifically.

In your `Procfile` add `?ssl_cert_reqs=none` to `$REDIS_URL`.

e.g.:

```
web: gunicorn webapp:app
worker: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL?ssl_cert_reqs=none queue
```

Don't update `REDIS_URL` directly as Heroku cycle this from time to time.

I also updated the Redis setup as per the original documentation:

```
url = urlparse(os.environ.get("REDIS_URL"))
r = redis.Redis(host=url.hostname, port=url.port, password=url.password, ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs=None)
```

But it was the change to the `Procfile` that finally got Redis v6.2.11 with TLS working correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works with redis 6 and python on Heroku

```py
import os, redis

redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_URL')
redis_store = redis.from_url(redis_url, ssl_cert_reqs=None)
```

In my local development environment I do not use redis with the rediss scheme, so I use a function like this to allow work in both cases:

```py
def get_redis_store():
    '''
    Get a connection pool to redis based on the url configured
    on env variable REDIS_URL

    Returns
    -------
    redis.ConnectionPool
    '''
    redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_URL')
    if redis_url.startswith('rediss://'):
        redis_store = redis.from_url(
            redis_url, ssl_cert_reqs=None)
    else:
        redis_store = redis.from_url(redis_url)
    return redis_store
```

Comment: Hey @GonzaloOdiard, Thanks a lot man! You just saved a lot of my time.
 
I have been wondering why is it not working, it was connecting with RedisInsight with TLS true, but wasn't getting integrated with python. I tried installing OpenSSL Certificates as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution works for nodejs16 and redis client 4.6.x

```
redisClient = redis.createClient({
            url: process.env.REDIS_URL,
            socket: {
                tls: true,
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            })
```