# How to enable TLS for Redis 6 on Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, redis

### Problem

On my Ruby on Rails app, I keep getting the error below for the [Heroku Redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis) Premium 0 add-on:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)

Heroku Redis [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#create-a-new-instance) mentions that I need to enable TLS in my Redis client's configuration in order to connect to a Redis 6 database. To achive this, I have read SSL/TLS Support documentation on [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb#ssltls-support). My understanding from it is; I need to assign `ca_file`, `cert` and `key` for `Redis.new#ssl_params`. *The question is* how to set these for Redis or through Sidekiq on Heroku?

### Updates

Update 3: Heroku support provided an answer which solved the problem.

Update 2: Created Heroku support ticket and waiting response.

Update 1: [Asked](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4786) on Sidekiq's Github issues and was adviced go write Heroku support. Will update this question, when I do get an answer.

---

#### Related Info

I have verified the app does work when the add-on is either one of the below:

- hobby-dev for Redis 6
- premium 0 for Redis 5

Versions:

- Ruby – 3.0.0p0
- Ruby on Rails – 6.1.1
- Redis – 6.0
- redis-rb – 4.2.5
- Sidekiq – 6.2.1
- Heroku Stack – 20

Some links that helped me to narrow down the issue:

- https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2020/11/24/are-you-talking-to-heroku-redis-in-cleartext-or-ssl/
- https://mislav.net/2013/07/ruby-openssl/

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65042551/ssl-certification-verify-failed-on-heroku-redis

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Solution

Use `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` for your Redis client.

#### Sidekiq

```rb
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE } }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE } }
end
```

#### Redis

```rb
Redis.new(url: 'url', driver: :ruby, ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })
```

## Reason

Redis 6 requires TLS to connect. However, Heroku support explained that they manage requests from the router level to the application level involving Self Signed Certs. Turns out, Heroku terminates SSL at the router level and requests are forwarded from there to the application via HTTP while everything is behind Heroku's Firewall and security measures.

---

**Sources**

- https://ogirginc.github.io/en/heroku-redis-ssl-error
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/securing-heroku-redis#connecting-directly-to-stunnel

Comment: The second part you can put into config/environment/production.rb as well. For example:

`config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], expires_in: 1.hour, ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE } }`

Comment: In my app, adding initializers did not work. My solution was to add `verify_mode` to the cable.yml config.

Comment: Also make sure your version of `redis` is at least than `4.0.2`.

According to Heroku, any version below ignores `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`.

This was our case with older versions of `resque` and old resque plugin versions. See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/securing-heroku-redis#connecting-directly-to-stunnel.

"This method only applies to versions of the `redis` gem `4.0.2` and up. `4.0.1` and below ignore `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` as a verification mode, and so cannot be used to connect to Heroku Redis over SSL natively."

Answer (score 9):

If you use ActionCable, you may also need to add `verify_mode` to the `cable.yml config:

```yaml
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: my_app_production
  ssl_params:
    verify_mode: <%= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE %>
```

Source: https://github.com/chatwoot/chatwoot/issues/2420

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Rails 5 you [won't be able to configure](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42036#issuecomment-885905472) Redis's `ssl_params` for ActionCable via the `cable.yml` file. Instead you can manually set the `redis_connector` attribute in an initializer, like this:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis"

ActionCable::SubscriptionAdapter::Redis.redis_connector = ->(_config) do
  Redis.new(...your options here...)
end
```

And for more context on the implications of using `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`  and why it's probably OK if you're on Heroku:

Using `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` tells the client it's OK to work with a self-signed certificate, no attempt will be made to verify that the cert was signed by a known Certificate Authority.

The risk there is the possibility of a man-in-the-middle attack. If the client attempting to talk to Heroku Redis is not verifying that the SSL certificates it encounters are known to belong to Heroku (AKA, that those certificates are signed by a certificate authority that has verified that the entity that requested the cert is in fact Heroku), then an attacker who sits betweeen your client and Heroku Redis could create their own self-signed SSL certificate and pretend to be Heroku. This means they could potentially intercept any traffic you attempt to send to Heroku Redis.

In practice that is probably not a realistic scenario for a Heroku dyno talking to Heroku Redis.

Here's a quote from Heroku support:

> MITM attacks are impractical on managed hosting providers. It would be
> difficult for a bad actor to get between a dyno and a Redis instance
> hosted on AWS. This is because EC2 instances that are in the same AZ
> should not route outside of the AWS infrastructure at any point. This
> being the case, a MITM attack could only be performed by a bad actor
> within the managed service provider's facility itself since the
> network traffic never leaves said facility.

And here are some snippets from the AWS docs that seem to corroborate this:

https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/

> Q. Does traffic go over the internet when two instances communicate
> using public IP addresses, or when instances communicate with a public
> AWS service endpoint?
>
> No. When using public address space, all communication between
> instances and services hosted in AWS use AWS's private network.
> Packets that originate from the AWS network with a destination on the
> AWS network stay on the AWS global network, except traffic to or from
> AWS China Regions.
>
> In addition, all data flowing across the AWS global network that
> interconnects our data centers and Regions is automatically encrypted
> at the physical layer before it leaves our secured facilities.
> Additional encryption layers exist as well; for example, all VPC
> cross-region peering traffic, and customer or service-to-service
> Transport Layer Security (TLS) connections.

And https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html

> Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) enables you to define a
> virtual network in your own logically isolated area within the AWS
> cloud, known as a virtual private cloud (VPC).
>
> When you create your AWS account, we create a default VPC for you in
> each Region